# Kotlin Performance

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, kotlin

I'm currently developing a library for android and i have a question that I can't find anywhere, is it faster to have different shapes and layouts and calling said layouts according to a method or just have on layout and change the color programmatically?

```kotlin
val d = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.success)
inflate(context,message,time, "#4caf50", d!!)
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/pill_custom"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/custom_toast_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/custom_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Inflating is very slow. Changing a color is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Color changing is faster, of course. Btw why dont you check it irl? Just make **N** inflating and **N** color changing in the test project print timestaps in log (`Log.i("tag", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));`) and calculate the difference.

Comment: Proper benchmarks are not quite that trivial.

Comment: @Tenfour04, of course, but if the difference between this two methods is really big, we will see it.

Comment: True. Just wanted to comment because I've seen quite a few questions on here where people were drawing incorrect conclusions from overly-simplistic benchmarking.

Answer (score 0):

Inflating a view will use some computing power of the phone so if you are focusing on performance, try to avoid inflating as much as possible.

I don't understand some of the things you have written in the question, but I noticed something about using a lot of layouts, using a lot of layouts increases the work in the main thread, so we have to use the elements directly without adding an extra LinearLayout, ConstraintLayout, etc if possible.